# FB API Get like of page

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to check if the user has liked the Facebook page. I request the user_likes permissions, I checked it and it returns that permission. So I guess I'm alright with the permissions.

Then I run the function getInfo. If I use "/me/likes/", I get all the likes of the user. But I want to check 1 page espacially. What am I doing wrong?

```
function getInfo(){
    FB.api(
        "/me/likes/id/",
        function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
            /* handle the result */
           console.log(response);
          }
        }
    );  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the

```
FB.api(
        "/me/likes/page-id",
        ...
```

code with an actual Page ID like this (for the CocaCola page):

```
FB.api(
        "/me/likes/40796308305",
        ...
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios#pagelikes
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes#readmodifiers

Comment: I did that.. That wasn't something I forgot.

But it seems that I used the idd of my app ;). Not the page.. Stupid mistake.  Thanks!

Comment: But be aware that your app will never be approved for user_likes if that is what you are using it for. And like gating is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy